What are these grey out import?

I am curious.
Why my .vb files have lots of greyed out import and it doesn't seem like I am the one writing it?
What are those?
Do I import that somewhere from some settings?
For example, I wonder where I put nethereum.contracts or other places. Are those imports that I simply do not use and hence can be deleted?
What?

The "greyed out" syntax highlighting indeed means imports that are not used in your code, and can safely be removed.

any sources? How do you know?
